# Inconsistency between daily voting limit and weekly votes after unupvote?

Tags: support, review, voting-limits

Earlier today, on another SE site, I casted 40 votes, so I reached my "*Daily up/down vote limit*". Because of that, I also see a message like "*Daily up/down vote limit reached; come back in X hours.*" for the review queues "First posts" (`/review/first-posts`) and "Late Answers" (`late-answers/stats`). So far no problem.

Later on today, 1 of the posts which I voted on (via 1 of my 40 votes from today) got edited. After that, I performed an **`unupvote`** for that post (which is possible after a post is edited). After I did so, I went back to check the review queues (at `/review`) to verify if I'd still have that message like "*Daily up/down vote limit reached; come back in X hours.*". Sure enough, that message was still there (and it's still there right now, many hours later).

A few minutes after I casted those 40 votes, I also went to check the total number of the votes I casted this week already, via `/users?tab=Voters&filter=week`. And a few minutes ago (= many hours later), I went back to check this `/users?tab=Voters&filter=week` again, since I was curious to see if an **`unupvote`** causes the number of votes I casted this week to be recalculated or not (somewhere in the minutes/hours after it happened). And sure enough: the number of votes I casted this week is now reduced with exactly 1. So far no problem, seems to work as it should.

**But**, as per this recalculation, it appears to me like the number of votes I casted today is `40-1=39`, so *I have the impression* I have 1 vote left for today. But if that is the case, then "*Daily up/down vote limit reached; come back in X hours.*" does no longer apply. Nevertheless, I still get that "*Daily up/down vote limit reached; come back in X hours.*" message in the 2 above mentioned review queues (the only difference is that the value of X went down ...).

Am I missing something, or is this to be considered as a bug?

PS: I haven't checked how my number of monthly/yearly/overall votes evolved today.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you're looking at the week view in the middle of the week. The vote you retracted today was actually cast *yesterday*, on the 9th. Remember that everything on our sites follows UTC time. It is now the 10th (soon the 11th), and when you retract a vote from a previous day, you do *not* get to cast that vote again today. You've used up all 40 of your votes for today and none of the votes you've cast today have been retracted. If you retracted one of the votes you actually cast today, you should be able to cast it again today.

Comment: Aha, **that** may be what I was missing! I hadn't thought about that scenario / combination. Give me some time to perform a similar experiment (too bad there is no such thing as test.stackexchange.com, and these kinds of tests always have to happen in operational environments).

Comment: Hey animuson, sorry to hijack this anser to post a new question. But knowing that my question here is the last question I asked (yesterday), and given the fact that the question is not downvoted, closed or deleted, and I have not received any other dwnvotes since yesterday, what could be a possible reason why "now" (1 day later) I get "**You have reached your question limit**"? Is there some rule in place like "If nothing else happens, I only have to wait like X days before asking a new question?". FYI: I discovered a new review-queue bug (I think ...), which is my new question I planned.